# Matplotlib How to add tilted lines and shapes outside of axes or cross different axes

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I wanna draw this graph using Matplotlib in Python. I already code the top part the the code is provided below. But I also want to draw few lines and two circles that look like the figure I drew below, does anyone know how to draw the lines and circles in Matplotlib? I need the line's color different based on whether the value is positive or negative (the data are provided)

[image]

```
grid_data = np.array([[[-0.1779874 , -0.90335705, -0.31157705,  0.77770067],
    [ 0.93698288,  0.79215241,  0.10155888,  0.96101718],
    [ 0.72994894, -0.83939131,  0.24713443,  0.74839211],
    [ 0.10039462, -0.95778299,  0.43554077,  0.61927077]],

   [[ 0.52294259, -0.0247383 ,  0.23717517, -0.0857769 ],
    [-0.43539246,  0.28503173, -0.39443502, -0.1478289 ],
    [-0.2327904 , -0.08339054,  0.33072907,  0.74634504],
    [-0.524284  , -0.72919194, -0.61543159,  0.17086563]]])
line_data = np.array([[-0.39126532,  0.40000044],
   [-0.79442062, -0.65220426],
   [ 0.2094217 ,  0.9531368 ]])
num_cols = 2
num_rows = 1
fig_size_h = 42/32*num_cols
fig_size_v = 14/10*num_rows
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = num_rows, ncols = num_cols, figsize = (fig_size_h, fig_size_v))
for i in range(num_cols):
    c = axes[i].pcolormesh(grid_data[i], cmap = 'RdBu_r', vmin = -1., vmax = 1.)
# Add a color bar
cb_ax = fig.add_axes([0.91, 0.13, 0.01, 0.75])
fig.colorbar(c, cax = cb_ax)
plt.show()
```

This code snippet only gives the two grids I have in the figure, but could you please help draw the circles and lines? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: `plt.Circle` is a circle. `plt.Line2D` is a line. They can be added to a figure via `fig.add_artist(..)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Hi, I feel like to draw a line, we have to do it within each axes, but the line I want to draw is cross different axes. Could you show me on my code how to make similar things?

Comment: If you want to create an axes, you can do so as well. Just from the drawing it looked like you do want to place the artists directly into the figure, hence my suggestion above.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest So should I create another 2 rows of empty axes, such that the entire figure has more space down at the bottom for me to draw those lines and circles? and then we could add those shape using `fig.add_artist(..)`